# How do I nest boxes/ elements using CSS?

Tags: html, css

So, I'm trying to nest elements within each other in CSS and so far having no luck. I've attached a photo of what my class activity is and I'm hoping for some guidance! The header, nav, and footer I was able to tackle no problems however the section and everything within as well as positioning the aside to the right and sizing have all been giving me a lot of trouble.

I was told by a classmate that the section needs to be relative and then everything within to use absolutely for but I've been fiddling for hours and nothing has worked.

This is my CSS style sheet so far - excuse the messy coding I've only been doing this for a week!

```
    body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#777;background:#777;width:960px;font-size: 18px}

#header {background: #ebebeb;height: 100px;text-align: center;line-height: 100px;}

#nav {background: #ebebeb;height: 100px;text-align: center;line-height: 100px;}

#section {background: #ebebeb;width: 495px;height: 300px;position: relative;z-index: auto;}

#aside {background: #ebebeb;width: 400px;}

#footer {background: #ebebeb;height: 100px;text-align: center;line-height: 100px;}

#article {color:#ebebeb;background: #777;position: absolute;z-index: 1;}

#h1 {color:#777;background: #ebebeb;position: absolute;z-index: 2;}

#p {color:#777;background: #ebebeb;position: absolute;z-index: 2;}

div {width: 495px;height:300px}
```

[This is what I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HscBH.png)

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by: "next elements within eachother"

Comment: Sorry about that - typo! Nest.

Comment: Can't you just put `<article>` inside `<section>` like this: `<article><section></section></article>`?

Comment: What was your initial task? Nesting elements using css and not html is kind of wrong.

Comment: Sorry - I should probably have clarified. This question is mainly about how to visually get the boxes to fit within one another like in the photo. So more of a CSS formatting/ styling questioning than HTML

Comment: Underneath my code snippit there is a link to an image of what I am trying to do visually. I don't really have the terminology down yet so wasn't really sure of how to phrase everything

Comment: @NicholasMatos check my answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D he's specific with what he want-- he needs guidance on how to make the image he attached.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this solution, the markup should consist of a div with `width:100%;` and the divs inside it should have `display:inline-block; width:49%;`.

- .container - `width:100%;`
- .section,.aside - `display:inline-block; width:49%;`

Preferably, I would use width:50% for section and aside, but using width:50% + padding pushes the aside div below section, which is why I used only 49%.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

.header,
.nav,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: silver;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/*css for section and aside*/

.section,
.aside {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49.4%;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/*css for content of section and aside*/

.section-content,
.aside-content {
  height: 180px;
  background-color: silver;
  padding: 5px;
}

.article {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.article-content {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.padding-container {
  padding: 5px;
}

.articles {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: silver;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <center>Header</center>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <center>Nav</center>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="section-content">
      <center>Section</center>
      <div class="article">
        <div class="article-content">
          <div class="padding-container">
            <center>Article</center>
            <div class="articles">
              <center><strong>h1, h2, h3</strong></center>
            </div>
            <div class="articles">
              <center>p</center>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="aside">
    <div class="aside-content">
      <center>Aside</center>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <center>Footer</center>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much! 

There are a couple of alterations I need to make to get the exact colors and whatnot but you were very helpful. I upvoted and marked as answered however I don't have enough reputation for my upvote to work haha.

Comment: @NicholasMatos There are other ways to do it hence they're saying that it's too broad. One of which is using flexboxes https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ Sure thing, goodluck with the project.

Comment: You are using the `<center>` tag which has been obsolete for several years. @JerdineSabio Do not use that element!

Comment: @Rob I see. That was just for the text anyway, it wasn't used to position the divs.